# Regular expression to get a class name from html

Tags: javascript, regex, performance

I know my question might look like a duplication for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195373/regular-expression-to-get-class-name-with-specific-substring), but its not

I am trying to match a class name inside **html text** that comes from the server as a template using JavsScript RegExp and replace it with another class name.
here what the code looks like :

```
<div class='a b c d'></div>
<!-- or -->
<div class="a b c d"></div>
<!-- There might be spaces after and before the = (the equal sign) -->
```

I want to match the class "b" for example
 with the highest performance possible

here is a regular expression I used but it's not working in all cases, and I don't know why :

```
  var key = 'b';
  statRegex = new RegExp('(<[\w+ class="[\\w\\s]*?)\\b('+key+')\\b([\\w\\s]*")');
  html.replace( statRegex,'SomeOtherClass');// I may be mistake by the way I am replacing it here
```

Comment: I know it is not faster than dom manipulation, but I am getting a text from the server not a dom and I am working with a special framework

Comment: Turning HTML into a DOM element is easy though ;-)

Comment: @AymanJitan You're being ignorant of the fact that HTML is not regular and therefor not a good fit for regular expressions. See http://htmlparsing.com/regexes.html. Using the DOM is obviously the best way to go.

Comment: @Bart I have widgets, each widget is made of many html templates, and inside each widget there is components with different states, the states are controlled by css classes, I need to parse the html and display the components and widgets in different states. its hard to explain though. I know that dom is much faster but it will not work in my case

Comment: @AymanJitan I can imagine it's complex but you're missing the point I'm trying to make. It's not so much about speed. It's about getting the correct results now and in the future. A regex will very likely fail when the formatting of the HTML changes as the DOM will give you reliable results.

Comment: @Bart thanks and I really understand, the html here is formatted and minified using a special loader, all in the same way.

Comment: I still don't get it. The replacement you want is super simple to make in DOM. After the change, use innerHTML to make a string again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a regex, this pattern should work for you:

```
var r = new RegExp("(<\\w+?\\s+?class\\s*=\\s*['\"][^'\"]*?\\b)" + key + "\\b", "i");
#                   Λ                                         Λ                  Λ
#                   |_________________________________________|                  |
#                           ____________|                                        |
# [Creating a backreference]                                                     |
# [which will be accessible]  [Using "i" makes the matching "case-insensitive".]_|
# [using $1 (see examples).]  [You can omit "i" for case-sensitive matching.   ]
```

E.g.

```
var oldClass = "b";
var newClass = "e";
var r = new RegExp("..." + oldClass + "...");

"<div class='a b c d'></div>".replace(r, "$1" + newClass);
    // ^-- returns: <div class='a e c d'></div>
"<div class=\"a b c d\"></div>".replace(r, "$1" + newClass);
    // ^-- returns: <div class="a e c d"></div>    
"<div class='abcd'></div>".replace(r, "$1" + newClass);
    // ^-- returns: <div class='abcd'></div>     // <-- NO change
```

NOTE:
For the above regex to work there must be no `'` or `"` inside the class string.
I.e. `<div class="a 'b' c d"...` will **NOT** match.

Comment: That's a whole new question :) Please, edit your question to clearly state what you are tryign to achieve (I'll update my answer).

Comment: sorry for that, but this regular expression matches the entire element, I am after matching the class only

Answer (score 3):

Use the browser to your advantage:

```
var str = '<div class=\'a b c d\'></div>\
<!-- or -->\
<div class="a b c d"></div>\
<!-- There might be spaces after and before the = (the equal sign) -->';

var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
wrapper.innerHTML = str;

var elements = wrapper.getElementsByClassName('b');

if (elements.length) {
    // there are elements with class b
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/isotam/1/)

Btw, `getElementsByClassName()` is not very well supported in IE until version 9; check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410949/javascript-document-getelementsbyclassname-compatibility-with-ie) for an alternative.

Comment: +1 Nice one. The only downside is that IE < 9 does not support `getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: @Bart Doesn't support what exactly? Oh, you mean `getElementsByClassName`?

Comment: this can be the perfect solution, but not in my case.
I am making some changes to the html before I inject it to the page, and dom will not help me in the framework I am working with.

Comment: @AymanJitan So make the changes in DOM? It's not very clear how the framework is stopping you from doing this.

Comment: @AymanJitan Make changes and get `wrapper.innerHTML`. Nothing simpler then that.

Answer (score 3):

Test it here: https://regex101.com/r/vnOFjm/1

regexp: `(?:class|className)=(?:["']\W+\s*(?:\w+)\()?["']([^'"]+)['"]`

```js
const regex = /(?:class|className)=(?:["']\W+\s*(?:\w+)\()?["']([^'"]+)['"]/gmi;
const str = `<div id="content" class="container">

<div style="overflow:hidden;margin-top:30px">
  <div style="width:300px;height:250px;float:left">
<ins class="adsbygoogle turbo" style="display:inline-block !important;width:300px;min-height:250px; display: none !important;" data-ad-client="ca-pub-1904398025977193" data-ad-slot="4723729075" data-color-link="2244BB" qgdsrhu="" hidden=""></ins>


<img src="http://static.teleman.pl/images/pixel.gif?show,753804,20160812" alt="" width="0" height="0" hidden="" style="display: none !important;">
</div>`;

let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are not a good fit for parsing HTML. HTML is not regular.

jQuery can be a very good fit here.

```
var html = 'Your HTML here...';

$('<div>' + html + '</div>').find('[class~="b"]').each(function () {
    console.log(this);
});
```

The selector `[class~="b"]` will select any element that has a `class` attribute containing the word `b`. The initial HTML is wrapped inside a `div` to make the `find` method work properly.

Comment: thanks, but I am not using jQuery and I am not willing to use dom manipulations

Answer (score -1):

This may not be a solution for you, but if you aren't set on using a full regex match, you could do (assuming your examples are representative of the data you will be parsing)
:

```
function hasTheClass(html_string, classname) {
    //!!~ turns -1 into false, and anything else into true. 
    return !!~html_string.split("=")[1].split(/[\'\"]/)[1].split(" ").indexOf(classname);
}

hasTheClass("<div class='a b c d'></div>", 'b'); //returns true
```

Comment: this overkills, using split this way will take much time